# CSS selector with deep level

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

in the following html/css code i want to select all elements "row" only on level 1 and not deeper. But the child selector also selects the nested "row" elements to?
How can i select only level 1 "row" elements?

```css
.content > .row
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 1</div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 2
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is working correctly, the green background is applied to only the parent row but the children row elements display it too. You can easily override that.

```css
.content > .row {
  background-color: green;
}
.content > .row .row { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 1</div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 2
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i thought i've maybe overseen a css selector. So can we say the other way round, there is no direct child only selector?

Comment: Selector just for a single child, no. Also, why the unaccept?

Comment: Sorry i've seen that "nishit chittora" was the first one who answered the question also correct, i wish i could set both of you on accepted :-(

Comment: Well you can see the answer timestamps to see which was the first one, but its alright

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behavior. Because it inherits background-color from parent element. But you can change the child element background-color

```css
.content > .row
{
  background-color: green;
}
.content > .row > .row{
  background-color: white
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 1</div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 2
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 1</div>
    <div class="row">Level 2 - Row 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">Level 1 - Row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the child will not inherit background, the backgroud apply to only the parent but will logically cover the child because they are inside.